# how to pass Authentication python openstack specific using request module or urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

how to pass these headers to validate my url

```
import requests
import sys
import json

auth_header = {"auth": {"tenantName": "XXXXX", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "XXX", "password": "XXXXXX"}}}
auth_url = 'xyz:1234/v2.0/'

requests_auth = requests.get(auth_url ,headers=auth_header)
status = requests_auth.status_code

print (status)
```

i get status code 200 when i pass it using curl

> curl -i -s -X POST https://Xxxxxx:000/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": “’”XXXXXX”’”, "passwordCredentials": {"username": “’”XXXXX’”, "password": “’”XXXXX”’”}}}’

Comment: and what do you get when you dont?  please post error stack

Comment: once you have tried something, that is...

Answer (score 0):

You are using *-d* option with curl which, according to [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded

If you want to achieve the same using python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module. You need to use the data parameter, as stated in [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

However you are also sending the application/json content-type header in your query, which seems misleading as the data is supposed to be url encoded. In any case, if what you want to send is indeed JSON encoded and not url encoded, you can use the json request parameter instead of data.

Last but not least, you are sending a POST request using curl (using -X option), and a GET request using requests. You should send a POST request using post function as stated in [requests documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post)

If you want to POST url encoded data:

```
import requests

auth = {"auth": {"tenantName": "XXXXX", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "XXX", "password": "XXXXXX"}}}
url = "xyz:1234/v2.0/"

response = requests.post(url, data=auth)
print(response.status_code)
```

If you want to POST JSON encoded data:

```
import requests

auth = {"auth": {"tenantName": "XXXXX", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "XXX", "password": "XXXXXX"}}}
url = "xyz:1234/v2.0/"

response = requests.post(url, json=auth)
print(response.status_code)
```